# App crashes on setContentView on specific device

Tags: android, layout

I am working on a tablet application on landscape mode and it currently supports only for large tablets. For this, I have created the following resource directory "layout-sw720dp-land" and I have xml layouts within this folder. In order to start my activity in landscape mode, I have set the screenOrientation attribute as landscape for my activities in the manifest as well.

I am using Samsung Tab A(SM-P580) for testing and it works well. 
But when the customer tries to load my app onto his Samsumg Tab S4(SM-T830) the app crashes on the line setContentView() with the below stacktrace,

```
.DashboardActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001c
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3041)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1711)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6960)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

To my knowledge, both of these tablets fall under the same size bucket and so both the tablets should be able to fetch the layout file from "layout-sw720dp-land" without any issues. But for some reason the Samsumg Tab S4 doesn't allow this. 
Is there any specific reason for this or am I missing something here? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your layout here?

Comment: Use to default layout folder and add a layout to be used as fallback. Then add specific layouts for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was causing the issue. In certain samsung devices, under **settings->accessibility->vision -> screen zoom and font**, the user will be able to choose a screen zoom.

And for me, the problem was when the screen zoom was set to max. This actually lowers the device resolution and in turn it makes the screen to look zoomed in.

As a result, the device resolution is lowered, and now when my app was loading, it started to look for layouts from sw-600dp folder where I didn't have my layout xml, since I was planning to have the app run only in 10 inch tablets.

So the solution is to either add layout files in sw-600dp to avoid the app crashing. Or to ask the user to change the screen zoom settings to min in order for the device to read the layout from sw-720dp bucket.